# Does Swift have a null coalescing operator and if not, what is an example of a custom operator?

Tags: swift

A common feature in many languages, the [Null Coalescing Operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_coalescing_operator), is a binary operator often used to shorten expressions of the type:

```
x = possiblyNullValue NCO valueIfNull
```

…where `NCO` is a placeholder for the language’s null coalescing operator.

Objective C's Null Coalescing Operator is `?:`, so the expression would be:

```
x = possiblyNullValue ?: valueIfNull
```

The above expression is also equivalent to the use of tertiary operator:

```
 x =  someTestForNotNull( possiblyNullValue ) ? possiblyNullValue : valueIfNull
```

### Advantages of a Null Coalescing Operator

- More readable code (especially with long, descriptive variable names)
- Reduced possibility of typographic errors (tested var is typed only once)
- No double evaluation of the tested variable where the tested variable is a getter, since its accessed once (or the need to cache it to intentionally avoid double evaluation).

Comment: As far as I can see, the closest thing it's got is `?.` for optional values, e.g. `let x = optionalObject?.value` won't cause an exception if `optionalObject` isn't set. It will quietly not evaluate `.value` and x will be an unset (i.e. `nil`) optional value.

Answer (score 57):

As of Swift 2.2 (*Xcode 6, beta 5*) it's `??`

```
var x: Int?
var y: Int? = 8

var z: Int = x ?? 9000
// z == 9000

z = y ?? 9001
// z == 8
```

`a ?? b` is equivalent to the following code:

```
a != nil ? a! : b
```

And as of Beta 6, you can do this:

```
x ?? y ?? 1 == 8
```

Comment: The `x ?? y ?? 1` did not work as you would expect in beta 5 (it would return `x`), but as of beta 6 it works (returning `y` in this case, or `1` if `y` were `nil` too).

Comment: Also, here's a nil coalescing *compound assignment* operator `x ??= y`: https://gist.github.com/268694f46ec8c135923c

Comment: Sorry if this is plainly obvious, but could you please tell me what the difference between using || and ?? in that case would be?

Answer (score 16):

(Also see [blog post](http://vperi.com/2014/06/05/null-coalescing-operator-elvis-in-swift/))

No, Swift doesn't currently support a null coalescing operator.

### Defining Custom Null Coalescing Operator for Swift

A custom operator can be defined for Swift, with the following considerations regarding the Swift language:

#### Swift and Nil

Swift supports a null concept through its *Optional* type (a Discriminated Union of sorts) which either holds a value of the underlying type or no value (indicated by nil) and must be explicitly defined as being optional:

```
var a : String?
```

A non-optional type can never be *nil*, or assigned nil. Therefore a custom infix binary NCO can be expected to take an optional as its first parameter.

#### Available Characters for Custom Operators in Swift

In Swift, custom operators can be comprised of the following characters only:

```
/ = - + * % < > ! & | ^ . ~
```

#### The Operator

Given the choice of available characters, **|||** (three pipes, no spacing) isn't terrible (similar to the double pipe OR in Javascript which is used like a NCO):

#### Using the Operator

```
var a = String?
var z = a ||| "it's nil!"
println(z) //Output: it's nil!
```

#### Defining the Operator

```
operator infix ||| {}

@infix func |||<T> (left: T?, right: T) -> T  {
  if let l = left { return l }
  return right
}
```

Comment: Nice use of a custom binary operator, +1

Comment: Suggestion: add `associativity left` inside the operator declaration so that you can type: let x = `foo ||| bar ||| baz ||| "it's nil"`

Comment: I'm trying to understand why it actually accepts two optionals, like in `optInt1 ||| optInt2` returning `nil` if both are `nil` or `{some x}` if one equals x. It seems like when the rhs is an optional, the `T` type becomes an optional itself.

Answer (score 8):

What Venkat says is correct: there is none but you can define one.
His implementation however is not ideal because he forgot to use `@auto_closure`.

Also I believe you can overload `||` without needing to define a new operator.

I do not have the compiler here, but I'll try to give you the code from memory:

```
func |||<T> (maybe: Optional<T>, defaultValue: @auto_closure () -> T) -> T {
    if let some = maybe { 
      return some 
    }
    return defaultValue()
}
```

Edit: Thanks to Martin R for testing this with the compiler. See the comments. Apparently overloading `||` is possible but may not work as expected because of the way Swift handles resolution of overloaded operators (which is undocumented and therefore I have no idea if it can be worked around or not). I've changed the function above to use `|||`.

Comment: At least in the Playground, `a || "it's nil!"` returns `true`, even with your overloaded definition. It works as expected if  your operator is called `|||`.

Comment: Interesting. It does not error on the overloaded definition, but it does not use it. Unfortunately there's no documentation that explains formally how Swift resolves overloads. If you have the compiler at hand you may try some experiments, or we can wait for more documentation from Apple. For the moment just go with a custom operator. I'll edit the answer to reflect your findings.

Comment: Same result in a compiled app.

Comment: Yep. I did not mean to try compiling. I meant trying to experiment with overloading and figure out what the overloading resolution algorithm is. I suspect it's the same that LLVM uses for C++, but unfortunately Swift soed not document it very well. And I do not think that there's a way to "instantiate" a generic manually, as you would have to do in C++ to make it a candidate when you have problems with automatic type conversion (I think the reason you get `true` is that it converts `a` and `"it's nil"` to booleans before trying to instantiate the generic to an overloaded implementation).

Comment: You could also experiment with things like `func |||<T>` and `func |||<T,O where O == Optional<T>>` (not sure if the syntax is correct, but that's the idea) and see what it does if there are both. And what if there ALSO are other overloads of `|||`, especially ones that admit some sort of automatic conversion.

Comment: Can you explain why your implementation is better than @VenkatPeri 's one?

Comment: @Teejay His implementation is strict in both arguments, mine is only strict in the first argument. You would expect this sort of operator to have lazy semantics at least in the second argument (also known as "short circuiting") and not compute the default value at all, if there already is a value. This is what I do, he doesn't.

Comment: @AnalogFile Uh ok, didn't know that `@auto_closure` implemented short-circuit evaluation. Thought was only for automatic statements surrounding.

Comment: @Teejay It is for automatically creating a closure surrounding the argument. And that is exactly how short circuit is implemented in applicative order languages. Instead of passing a value, which in applicative order makes the computation strict, you create a closure which may be lazily evaluated.

Answer (score 2):

I blogged about a custom operator function that provides nil-coalescing here:
http://ijoshsmith.com/2014/07/24/nil-coalescing-operator-in-swift/

My choice of operator was `!!` which combines the logical not operator (!) and the unwrap operator (!) for a "if cannot unwrap" semantic. Seems I was late to the party, given this thread is already over a month old. Either way, here's my implementation in case you're interested...

```
operator infix !! {}

@infix func !! <T> (
    value: T?,
    defaultValue: @auto_closure () -> T)
    -> T
{
    return value ? value! : defaultValue()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

hope this will help you

1. yes , Now it is added in swift
2. little Explanation

   ```
          var anumber:Int? = someValue
          var banumber = 2
          anumber =   ( anumber != nil) ? anumber : banumber ------- (a)
          println(anumber!)
   ```

now instead of writing all (a) this we can just use this ->

```
        anumber = anumber ?? banumber
```

and

The operator can also be used multiple times in the same expression.
like

```
     firstNumber ?? secondNumber ?? thirdNumber.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check with playground code below.

```
import UIKit
var personalSite : String?
let defaultSite = "http://www.google.com"

var website = personalSite ?? defaultSite
```