# Providing a default value for an Optional in Swift?

Tags: swift, option-type

The idiom for dealing with optionals in Swift seems excessively verbose, if all you want to do is provide a default value in the case where it's nil:

```
if let value = optionalValue {
    // do something with 'value'
} else {
    // do the same thing with your default value
}
```

which involves needlessly duplicating code, or

```
var unwrappedValue
if let value = optionalValue {
    unwrappedValue = value
} else {
    unwrappedValue = defaultValue
}
```

which requires `unwrappedValue` not be a constant.

Scala's Option monad (which is basically the same idea as Swift's Optional) has the method `getOrElse` for this purpose:

```
val myValue = optionalValue.getOrElse(defaultValue)
```

Am I missing something? Does Swift have a compact way of doing that already? Or, failing that, is it possible to define `getOrElse` in an extension for Optional?

Comment: Possibly related: [Does Swift have a null coalescing operator and if not, what is an example of a custom operator?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24082959/does-swift-have-a-null-coalescing-operator-and-if-not-what-is-an-example-of-a-c)

Answer (score 317, accepted):

**Update**

Apple has now added a coalescing operator:

```
var unwrappedValue = optionalValue ?? defaultValue
```

---

The ternary operator is your friend in this case

```
var unwrappedValue = optionalValue ? optionalValue! : defaultValue
```

You could also provide your own extension for the Optional enum:

```
extension Optional {
    func or(defaultValue: T) -> T {
        switch(self) {
            case .None:
                return defaultValue
            case .Some(let value):
                return value
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can just do:

```
optionalValue.or(defaultValue)
```

However, I recommend sticking to the ternary operator as other developers will understand that much more quickly without having to investigate the `or` method

**Note**: I started a [module](https://github.com/drewag/SwiftPlusPlus) to add common helpers like this `or` on `Optional` to swift.

Comment: my complier shows me that the type of `unwrappedValue` is still the optional type for this case in Swift 1.2: `var unwrappedValue = optionalValue ? optionalValue! : defaultValue` (xcode 6 beta 4). Has this changed?

Comment: I'm wrong on my version. I'm on 6.4. Be aware: `??` default type inference behavior is that it returns an optional, which is not what you want typically. You can declare the variable as non-optional and this works nicely.

Answer (score 31):

As of Aug 2014 Swift has coalescing operator (??) that allows that. For example, for an optional String myOptional you could write:

```
result = myOptional ?? "n/a"
```

Answer (score 7):

if you wrote:

```
let result = optionalValue ?? 50
```

and  `optionalValue != nil` then `result` will be `optional` too  and you will need unwrap it in future

But you can write operator

```
infix operator ??? { associativity left precedence 140 }

func ???<T>(optLeft:T?, right:T!) -> T!
{
    if let left = optLeft
    {
        return left
    }
    else { return right}
}
```

Now you can:

```
 let result = optionalValue ??? 50
```

And when  `optionalValue != nil` then  `result` will be `unwraped`

Answer (score 3):

The following seems to work

```
extension Optional {
    func getOrElse<T>(defaultValue: T) -> T {
        if let value = self? {
            return value as T
        } else {
            return defaultValue
        }
    }
}
```

however the need to cast `value as T` is an ugly hack. Ideally, there should be a way to assert that `T` is the same as the type contained in the Optional. As it stands, type inferencing sets `T` based on the parameter given to getOrElse, and then fails at runtime if this does not match the Optional and the Optional is non-nil:

```
let x: Int?

let y = x.getOrElse(1.414) // y inferred as Double, assigned 1.414

let a: Int? = 5

let b: Double = a.getOrElse(3.14) // Runtime failure casting 5 to Double
```

Comment: You do not need to specify `T` for the method. That actually overrides the existing `T` from Optional. You can just do: `func getOrElse(defaultValue: T) -> T` then T refers to the real value type of the optional and you don't have to type check it

Comment: Thanks! I inferred exactly that from the second half of your response. Is there some way to inspect the definition of Optional to know that the generic type is defined as `T` in that? (beyond simply assuming based on convention)

Comment: If you command-click on `Optional` inside Xcode, you will see that it is defined as `enum Optional<T>`

Comment: Oh, excellent. I should have guessed. The definitions in there will be useful; there's a lot of things that aren't in the documentation yet. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to do this with a String you can do this ..

```
string1 = string2.isEmpty ? "Default Value":string2
```