# Default value optional swift doesnt make it nonOptional

Tags: ios, swift

I set a default string value with the ?? operator. But i get an optional String?

```
    request(.GET, CUSTOMER_URL, parameters: params, encoding: .URL).responseJSON { (request, response, result) -> Void in
        var message = JSON(result.value ?? "")["message"].string ?? "Default value to make it nonOptional"
        switch(result) {
        case .Success(let json):
            if let customer = JSON(json)["customer"].dictionaryObject {
                GlobalCache.sharedInstance.setCustomer(customer)
            }
            completion(succeed: response?.statusCode == 200, message: message)
        case .Failure(_,_):
            completion(succeed: false, message: message)
        }
    }
```

[image: message is String?]

Expected behaviour

[image]

Unexpected behaviour

[image]

Comment: I know that, my question is why is an optional since i'm providing a default value. Post edited.

Comment: Is the `JSON` class your custom one or some 3rd party library to take a look at it?

Comment: https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON/tree/xcode7

Answer (score 1):

What version of Xcode do you use? I couldn't reproduce specified behaviour in Xcode 7 GM (7A218). If your version is lower it looks like a bug in previous beta.

[image]

Comment: It's a mysticism... I think we just need a third person to test this case in their 7A218 build.

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to [Providing a default value for an Optional in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24099985/providing-a-default-value-for-an-optional-in-swift)

You can use a type annotation to force a non-optional value:

```
var message: String = JSON(result.value ?? "")["message"].string ?? "Default value"
```

Comment: But again the right side of the question should be evaluated to string not to optional string

Comment: did you see my images?

Comment: Of course you can, but I don't think that is what is wanted. `Using let optString: String? = nil
var message = optString ?? "Default value"` also sets `message` to "Default value" with type `String`. The question is more like, why isn't it without optional, because the ?? operator does that in other contexts as well.

Comment: I don't really see any good reason why the type defaults to `String?` here. My best explanation is that this is a bug in the language.

Comment: Or in the particular environment as it showed my test above.