# Swift if value is nil set default value instead

Tags: swift

I have this code part:

```
let strValue = String()
textfield.stringValue = strValue!
```

The problem is that `strValue` can be nil.

For this I check it like this:

```
if strValues.isEmpty() {
   textfield.stringValue = ""
} else {
   textfield.stringValue = strValue!
}
```

But I there an quicker and easier way to do this?

I read something like `??` to solve it. But I don't know how to use it?

**UPDATE**
thanks a lot for the many feedbacks.
now i unterstand the ?? operator, but how i realize it in this situation?

```
let person = PeoplePicker.selectedRecords as! [ABPerson]
let address = person[0].value(forProperty: kABAddressProperty) as?
        ABMultiValue
txtStreet.stringValue = (((address?.value(at: 0) as! NSMutableDictionary).value(forKey: kABAddressStreetKey) as! String))
```

how can i usee the ?? operator in the last line of my code?

**UPDATE 2**
Okay i got it!

```
txtStreet.stringValue = (((adresse?.value(at: 0) as? NSMutableDictionary)?.value(forKey: kABAddressStreetKey) as? String)) ?? ""
```

Comment: Do you mean `nil` or an empty string `""`?

Comment: The nil coalescing operator does the job concisely: `textField.stringValue = strValue ?? ""`

Comment: Probably a duplicate of [Providing a default value for an Optional in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24099985/2976878), but your question makes no sense because `strValue` is not optional.

Comment: Your *code part* does not compile because `strValue` is clearly non-optional.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

you can do like this but your strValue should be optional type

```
let strValue:String?
textfield.stringValue = strValue ?? "your default value here"
```

Answer (score 3):

Using **nil-coaleasing operator**, we can avoid code to unwrap and clean our code.

To provide simple default value when an optional is nil :

```
let name : String? = "My name"
let namevalue = name ?? "No name"
print(namevalue)
```

Important thing to note here is that you don't need to unwrap it using **if let** or **guard** here and it will be **implicitly unwrapped but safely**.

Also it is useful to make your code much cleaner and short :

```
   do {
        let text = try String(contentsOf: fileURL, encoding: .utf8)
    }
    catch {print("error")}
```

Above code can be written as :

```
let text = (try? String(contentsOf: fileURL, encoding: .utf8)) ?? "Error reading file"
```

Comment: What if the part after the ?? needs a few lines of code?

Answer (score 2):

The `??` is the nil-coalescing operator, and took me a bit to understand, too. It is a useful tool for simplifying code though. A simple explanation of it is "unless that's nil, then this" so `a ?? b` returns `a` if it has a value and `b` if it doesn't.  You can chain them together and return the first non-nil value. Example, `a ?? b ?? c ?? d ?? e` returns the first non-nil value, or `e` if they are all nil before it.

[Nil-Coalescing Operator](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH6-ID72)

Answer (score 1):

You can create an optional string extension. I did the following to set an optional string to empty if it was nil and it works :

```
extension Optional where Wrapped == String {

    mutating func setToEmptyIfNil() {
        guard self != nil else {
            self = ""
            return
        }
    }

}
```