# Objective-C : Implicit declaration of function 'isEmptyString' is invalid in c99

Tags: objective-c, boolean, ternary

Following is the mentioned function :-

```
-(BOOL) isEmptyString :(NSString*) string {
    if([string isEqualToString:@""] || [string isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

While using this function as follows:-

```
BOOL d = isEmptyString(@"data");
```

raises afore mentioned dont know why. Can someone explain as to what am i doing wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You declared the function in objective-c but you are calling it as if it was a c function.

You should either change the declaration or change the way you call it.

You should call it this way (assuming you are in the same .m file)

`BOOL d = [self isEmptyString:@"data"]`

Comment: Thanks Aris. Actually i am more into swift and there is no defaulting operator which i know of in objective-c.

Comment: No Problem! What do you mean with "defaulting operator"?

Comment: ?? in swift is defaulting operator

Comment: Ah yea understood.

Comment: so is there anything similar in objective-c for defaulting ?

Comment: I don't think so.. the only thing that comes close is this I think `x =  someTestForNotNull( possiblyNullValue ) ? possiblyNullValue : valueIfNull` taken from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24082959/does-swift-have-a-null-coalescing-operator-and-if-not-what-is-an-example-of-a-c